# creating a WebRTC application which works without taking permission from user

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I wants to create WebRTC application that doesn't ask user for Allow/Deny permission.

I am able to implement it in the browser which ask for permission to use webcam and microphone.
[image: permmision allow/deny]

I want a solution where webcam and microphone permissions are granted by default.

Is there any other thing which I can use instead of browser? A standalone application or something?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's not possible what you wanted.

Comment: No i don't think the solution you are requesting is available at the moment. There is always restrictions like this for a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously... at least one time, the user must allow that your page uses the camera and/or mic.
And it's a good thing that it is mandatory, because I wouldn't like to enter your page and just get listened or seen without being noticed.

But... If you have your page available in https, users will only need to allow the access to media devices once. After the first acceptance, when you call getUserMedia, you get the streams immediately in the success callback.
The same happens when the user declines access. The next time you request access, user won't be notified, and you just get the reject callback called.

The user acceptance is saved per domain only for secure pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your app with [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). I just tested version 2.0.6, there is no user confirmation requested.